# Android app crashes when creating Listview in fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-fragments

My application always crashes everytime I move to this activity. I think the problem is in creating and populating ListView in Fragment.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_routines,
                container, false);

        ListView list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_routines);
        populateListView(list);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void populateListView(ListView list){


        String[] items = null;
        int work = 1;
        switch(work){

            case 1:
                items = new String[]{"Dumbbell Curls","Dumbbell Kickbacks","Bench Dips","Dumbbell Hammer Curls", "Diamond Pushups", "Dumbbell Flyes"};
                break;
            case 2:
                items = new String[]{"Squats","Plank","Lunges","Leg Raises","Calf Raises","Crunches"};
                break;
            case 3:
                items = new String[]{"Dumbbell Rows","Superman","Arnold Press","Dumbbell Reverse Flyes","Lateral Raises","Pull-Up"};
                break;
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.routine_items,
                items
                );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

This is the activity which placeholderfragment class is within:

```
public class ListRoutinesActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static int type;
private static Context list_context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_routines);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

This is my fragment_list_routines.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tutorial.ListRoutinesActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_routines"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
```

this is my routine_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</TextView>
```

This is the error logs:

```
    03-09 20:26:58.354: I/PGA(7016): New SOCKET connection: com.example.tutorial (pid 7016, tid 7016)
03-09 20:27:01.904: D/AndroidRuntime(7016): Shutting down VM
03-09 20:27:01.904: W/dalvikvm(7016): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d9cb20)
03-09 20:27:01.904: D/AndroidRuntime(7016): procName from cmdline: com.example.tutorial
03-09 20:27:01.904: E/AndroidRuntime(7016): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.tutorial
03-09 20:27:01.934: I/Process(7016): Sending signal. PID: 7016 SIG: 9
03-09 20:27:01.934: D/AndroidRuntime(7016): file written successfully with content: com.example.tutorial StringBuffer : ;com.example.tutorial
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016): Process: com.example.tutorial, PID: 7016
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method arms_and_chest(View) in the activity class com.main.workoutinstructor.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_arms'
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3815)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4443)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18433)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: arms_and_chest [class android.view.View]
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3808)
03-09 20:27:01.934: E/AndroidRuntime(7016):     ... 11 more
```

Can't find the solution for hours. Still a beginner in android hehe

Comment: Can you please post crash log?

Comment: what is `private static Context list_context;` ? for?

Comment: *Could not find a method arms_and_chest(View)*

Comment: @Blackbelt dont mind it, i've used to reference the activity before in the fragment class, now, i use getActivity() method.

Comment: Where have you defined btn_arms Button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your app crashes at this :

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: arms_and_chest [class android.view.View]`

You will need to define this method if you want to use it.

It seems that your XML is referencing this method, via button

`for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btn_arms'`

find this reference in your XML and either remove this and define an OnClickListener in your Code, or add this method to your activity:

```
 public void arms_and_chest(View view){
     // ... Operations here

 }
```

Comment: Thanks! it works now :) the error is in the spelling of the reference from xml to the class method. hahaha